# Is there any difference in meaning between "match something with something" and "check something against something"?

Tags: difference

Is there any difference in meaning between *match something with something* and *check something against something*? For example:

> I am not sure if got all the answers right, so I had better **match** mine **with** yours.
>
> I am not sure if got all the answers right, so I had better **check** mine **against** yours.

Comment: If you match his questions you simply put the same answers;  if you see if your questions match his, you verify that they correspond.

Comment: Are you sure you mean “questions” and not “answers”?

Comment: You are right . Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To match something with something** = to find similarities between two things.

**To check something against something** = to inspect the accuracy between two things or to examine that which one out of two is more accurate.

---

> I am not sure if I got all the answers right, so I’d better match mine with yours.

This sentence emphasises that you are looking for similarities between two answers to find out if your answer matches with the answer of that person.

> I am not sure if I got all the answers right, so I’d better check mine against yours.

This sentence emphasises that you are examining the accuracy between your answer and that person’s answer in order to find out that which one is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! You wrote "check match" in your first sentence. I suppouse  it's a typo, so I edited it.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo.